# What happened to Lovon's idols that were taken by Rochel?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avodah-zarah, rachel-imenu, lavan

In a comment on this question [Did anyone (especially Yaakov) ever find out about the idols?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97007/did-anyone-especially-yaakov-ever-find-out-about-the-idols) Ezra [says](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97007/did-anyone-especially-yaakov-ever-find-out-about-the-idols#comment321842_97007):

> In Genesis 35:1-4, Jacob requests his household to hand over "foreign
> deities", and he buries them underneath a tree in Shechem. Perhaps the
> teraphim were discovered then, because shortly after this, Rachel dies
> (ibid. 35:17-20).

Other than this suggestion, do we know what happened to Lovon's idols that were taken by Rochel?

Comment: Presumably, they were destroyed in the same manner all Avodah Zora is supposed to be destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of sources state that they were transformed into household objects:

[Beresheet Rabbah 74:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereshit_Rabbah.74.9?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi):

> "אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן תְּרָפִים לֹא מָצָא קִיתוֹנִיּוֹת מָצָא, נַעֲשׂוּ תְּרָפִים קִיתוֹנִיּוֹת שֶׁלֹא לְבַיֵּשׁ אֶת רָחֵל."
> "Rabbi Yochanan said: He did not find teraphim, but he found jugs. The household idols were transformed into jugs so as not to embarrass Rachel."

Midrash Aggadah (an anoymous commentary on Beresheet), [p. 80](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33177&st=&pgnum=94):

> "...וחזר ופשפש בכר הגמל ונעשה נס לרחל ונעשו התרפים כר מלא נוצה"
> "and he rummaged through the cushion of the camel, and a miracle happened to Rachel and the teraphim became a cushion filled with feathers."

It's possible they stayed that way (consider for example [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/137791/20472)) and could then be used in a legitimate manner.